# WPF Custom Control controls misalignment

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface

In my visual designer I see this:

[image]

However, in the actual app I see this:

[image]

Why is everything so off? How do I make it look the way I see stuff in the designer?

User Control `XAML`:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyNamespace.UserControlCard"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Margin="0,0,0,0"
    d:DesignHeight="877"
    d:DesignWidth="622"
    GotFocus="UserControl_GotFocus"
    Loaded="UserControl_Loaded"
    LostFocus="UserControl_LostFocus"
    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/img/Card Background.png" />
    </UserControl.Background>

    <UserControl.LayoutTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" />
            <SkewTransform />
            <RotateTransform />
            <TranslateTransform />
        </TransformGroup>
    </UserControl.LayoutTransform>

    <Border
        x:Name="BorderFocus"
        BorderBrush="White"
        BorderThickness="5"
        Visibility="Visible">

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image
                x:Name="CardImage"
                Width="242"
                Height="295"
                Margin="27,38,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Source="/icons/rules.png"
                Stretch="Uniform"
                StretchDirection="Both" />
            <TextBlock
                x:Name="lblName"
                Width="256"
                Height="56"
                Margin="324,89,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                FontFamily="Bahnschrift Condensed"
                FontSize="36"
                Foreground="White"
                Text="Lorem Ipsum"
                TextAlignment="Left"
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            <TextBlock
                x:Name="lblRace"
                Width="256"
                Height="56"
                Margin="324,166,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                FontFamily="Bahnschrift Condensed"
                FontSize="36"
                Foreground="White"
                Text="Human"
                TextAlignment="Left"
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            <TextBlock
                x:Name="lblAge"
                Width="256"
                Height="56"
                Margin="324,244,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                FontFamily="Bahnschrift Condensed"
                FontSize="36"
                Foreground="White"
                Text="20 years."
                TextAlignment="Left"
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            <TextBlock
                x:Name="lblDescription"
                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                Width="548"
                Height="102"
                Margin="0,368,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                FontFamily="Bahnschrift Condensed"
                FontSize="20"
                Foreground="White"
                Text="Lorem Ipsum is truly a magnificent warrior. He is known for his great accomplishments on Earth battle. There is no better example of a brave person, than Lorem Ipsum - the one chosen by the universe itself, able to influence the outcome of The World Wars. Everyone is scared by pure thought of meeting him on the battlefield."
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            <TextBlock
                x:Name="lblFirst"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Margin="32,134,498,259"
                FontFamily="Bahnschrift Condensed"
                FontSize="36"
                Foreground="White"
                Text="50"
                TextAlignment="Center"
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            <ProgressBar
                x:Name="FirstBar"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Margin="128,136,84,257"
                Foreground="#FF29C93F"
                LargeChange="0"
                SmallChange="1"
                Value="50" />
            <TextBlock
                x:Name="lblSecond"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Margin="32,208,498,184"
                FontFamily="Bahnschrift Condensed"
                FontSize="36"
                Foreground="White"
                Text="50"
                TextAlignment="Center"
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            <ProgressBar
                x:Name="SecondBar"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Margin="128,208,84,185"
                Foreground="#FFFF4545"
                LargeChange="0"
                SmallChange="1"
                Value="50" />
            <TextBlock
                x:Name="lblThird"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Margin="32,284,498,109"
                FontFamily="Bahnschrift Condensed"
                FontSize="36"
                Foreground="White"
                Text="50"
                TextAlignment="Center"
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            <ProgressBar
                x:Name="ThirdBar"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Margin="128,286,84,108"
                Foreground="#FF49DFE6"
                LargeChange="0"
                SmallChange="1"
                Value="50" />
            <TextBlock
                x:Name="lblFourth"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Margin="32,358,498,34"
                FontFamily="Bahnschrift Condensed"
                FontSize="36"
                Foreground="White"
                Text="50"
                TextAlignment="Center"
                TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            <ProgressBar
                x:Name="FourthBar"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Margin="128,358,84,35"
                Foreground="#FFDCB752"
                LargeChange="0"
                SmallChange="1"
                Value="50" />

        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

Where I want my card to be displayed in (added in-code as `PanelCards.Children` item):

```
<ScrollViewer
            Margin="0,0,220,162"
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

            <WrapPanel
                x:Name="PanelCards"
                Width="1050"
                Margin="0,0,225,182"
                Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ScrollViewer>
```

EDIT: What is the best practice to set everything in the correct places? @mm8 mentioned using panels, but I am very fresh to WPF technology and I can't figure out, which panels and how should I use.

If you need a reference for the layout, check [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2Mhq.jpg).

Comment: Do not use margins to layout the elements. Use an appropriate panel.

Comment: @mm8 like I said I'm a WPF newbie, wouldn't be using panels make them have weird margins, hence not solving the issue? Could you show an example for 1-2 of my text blocks so I can see the principle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove any margin that is over 20 pixels such as `Margin="32,134,498,259"`. Because these *funky* margins exist, they are pushing the text (as you have seen) into locations which are not wanted.

Clean up your code as mentioned, maybe put things into a grid which will anchor the controls in a better fashion; and don't use `Margin`s or `Padding`s only when small spaces need to be adjusted.

Comment: Well if I am to group stuff into grids, then these grids also need to have *funky* margins, no? Could you do a snippet for 1-2 of my labels so I could know more clearly what you mean?

Comment: Here is an example to get you started on working with grids [The Grid Control](https://wpf-tutorial.com/panels/grid/). My point is, that a grid is a panel which can hold controls and position them in specific locations; that is the more preferred route to such anchoring than using margins. I use margins, but its the last step I would do to finalize a look and not the first.